# Is it possible to use PostSharp 3 with Visual Studio Express?

Tags: visual-studio, postsharp

PostSharp 3 is available only as a visual studio extension. Visual Studio Express don't support extension. Is there a way to use PostSharp 3 with Express version of Visual Studio?

Previously we use PostSharp 2.1 as an external tools with free PostSharp express license, but currently this [license is not available](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/1007-mr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it is possible, using Nuget package. Actually, you should add reference to Postsharp Nuget to all projects that are failed for compile.

In my case, I have a postsharp reference in some referenced project and Console app project and WebApplication projects required to have reference to package too.

To provide license just go to package folder and run Postsharp.HQ.v.3.0.exe

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer from PostSharp tech support:

PostSharp 2.1 Starter editions are not available any more. However, PostSharp 3 does not work in VS Express.